# Metric pull-back along the stereographic projection

Tags: differential-geometry

For one of my tutorial questions in GR I have been asked to find charts for the two sphere, together with the expression for the infinitesimal line element on $S^2$. I defined the charts with the stereographic projection (in cartesian coordinates), and the line element by restricting the 3D Euclidean metric in spherical coordinates to the sphere. But then I was wondering what the pull-back under the stereographic projection of the 2D-euclidean metric would look like. To make the calculation a bit nicer, I did this in spherical coordinates. Thus, $$\Phi: S^2-\{S\} \to R^2, (\phi, \theta) \mapsto \Big(\frac{sin(\phi)}{1-cos(\phi)}, \theta\Big) = \big(R, \Omega \big)$$

defines the stereographic projection and $$ds^2 = d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$

defines the restricted 3D Euclidean metric. However, when computing the pull back under $\Phi$ of the 2D Euclidean metric, given by $d\Omega^2 + R^2dR^2$, I seem to get a rather nasty expression, not at all the same as the nice expression of the restricted metric.

Comment: You're mixing your two different spherical coordinate systems. And your Euclidean metric is totally wrong!

Comment: If you want to write the standard spherical metric in stereographic coordinates, it's best to avoid spherical coordinates entirely and use only Cartesian coordinates. Find the formula from $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to $(x,y,z) \in S^2\backslash \{0,0,1\}$. The spherical metric is the Euclidean metric $g_E = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ restricted to $S^2$. Just compute $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ in terms of $du$ and $dv$ and substitute into $g_E$. The result will be what you're looking for. If you do things correctly, it will be of the form $f(u,v)(du^2 + dv^2)$.